# How to get the referenced entity name instead of target_id in Normalizers?

Tags: 8, entities

I am working on exposing the article type content via REST in JSON format. I am using Normalizers to generate the required data format.

Normalizer:

```
use Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer;

/**
 * StdClass normalizer.
 */
class NewsFeedNormalizer extends ContentEntityNormalizer {

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public function normalize($entity, $format = NULL, array $context = []) {
    $node_detail = parent::normalize($entity, $format, $context);
    // $news_data = [];
    $news_data['id'] = $node_detail['nid'][0]['value'];
    $news_data['type'] = $node_detail['field_story_type'][0]['target_id'];
    $news_data['title'] = $node_detail['title'][0]['value'];
    $news_data['summary'] = $node_detail['body'][0]['summary'];

    return $news_data;
  }

}
```

Tha above code will return `target_id` in `$news_data['type']`. But I need to pass label of the term which is referred. I tried with another Normalizer called `EntityReferenceFieldItemNormalizer` But there also i didn't get the required result.  Can anyone help me in this regard? Any suggestions will be apprceiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the target id so just load the term and send the label instead of target id, something like :

```
$tid = $node_detail['field_story_type'][0]['target_id'];
$term  =  \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid);
$news_data['type'] = $term->label();
```

**Note:** you are in class it's better to inject `entity.manager` service and change the line `\Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid);` with something like:

```
$this->entityManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
```

Comment: Hi @berramou.  I agree with this. But I was looking for like instead of loading the terms is there any direct way to get the names of terms. As there is a separate normalizer call EntityReferenceFieldItemNormalizer. So i just wondering whether it could help in this way.